# How to use instance specific topics in Kafka streams?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have this topology:

```
Topology topology = new Topology();

//WS connection processor
topology.addSource(WS_CONNECTION_SOURCE, new StringDeserializer(), new WebSocketConnectionEventDeserializer(), KafkaTopics.WS_CONNECTION_EVENTS_TOPIC)
    .addProcessor(SESSION_PROCESSOR, WSUserSessionProcessor::new, WS_CONNECTION_SOURCE)
    .addStateStore(sessionStoreBuilder, SESSION_PROCESSOR)
    .addSink(WS_STATUS_SINK, KafkaTopics.WS_USER_ONLINE_STATUS_TOPIC, stringSerializer, stringSerializer, SESSION_PROCESSOR)

//WS session routing
    .addSource(WS_ROUTING_BY_SESSION_SOURCE, new StringDeserializer(), new StringDeserializer(),
                    KafkaTopics.WS_DELIVERY_TOPIC)
    .addProcessor(WS_ROUTING_BY_SESSION_PROCESSOR, WSSessionRoutingProcessor::new,
                    WS_ROUTING_BY_SESSION_SOURCE)
    .addStateStore(userConnectedNodesStoreBuilder, WS_ROUTING_BY_SESSION_PROCESSOR, SESSION_PROCESSOR)

//WS delivery
    .addSource(WS_DELIVERY_SOURCE, new StringDeserializer(), new StringDeserializer(),
                    INSTANCE_SPECIFIC_TOPIC)
    .addProcessor(WS_DELIVERY_PROCESSOR,  WSDeliveryProcessor::new, WS_DELIVERY_SOURCE);
```

The source mentioned last in the topology is topic specific to each app instance. I want that topic to be processed only by that instance. The data to this topic is pushed by the previous processor based on which instance has to process that message.

But once stream is started, it is trying to assign instance specific topic partitions also to other instances. Can we achieve this requirement in Kafka streams?

I want one topic to be processed only by specific instance.

Comment: as an option, you might add specific source and processor only on the required instance:
`if (specificInstance) { topology. addSource(.., INSTANCE_SPECIFIC_TOPIC) }`

Comment: all instances need their own instance specific topic. Processor logic is the same

Comment: If there are 3 instances, I create 3 topics each for specific instance. So final topic has to be processed only by each instance and not distributed across instances

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible. For a Kafka Streams program, all instances of the same application need to be exactly the same and thus need to have the same input topics.

You would need to split your application into 4 apps: the first app executes the shared partition of the program and writes into the 3 different topics. Additionally, you have 3 more applications (with own `application.id`s) each reading from one those topics.

Note that if you want, you can run multiple `KafkaStreams` clients in the same JVM.

Comment: I modified the topology such each instance has 2 application ids. One app id is common to all instances and uses shared topics and the second one has different source topic for each instance and uses different app id. Hope this is fine

Comment: I have a related question. Once a topology is created, we cannot change the structure of the topology for the same app id. What kind of changes breaks the stream and what changes are possible? - Changing source topics, changing topic partitions, changing sink topics, adding/removing processors

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand: however, if you deploy different instances that run the same code but connect to different input topic, you need to use different `application.id`s for each instance -- they cannot share the same `application.id` because which topic a program reads from is part of the program and thus its different programs that need different `application.id`s. -- About what changes are compatible: most changes are incompatible and should you reset you application before re-deploying: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/app-reset-tool.html